# Is there a way to explode arrays of associative arrays into one array without loosing the keys in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of arrays of associative arrays like this

```
$my_array = [
  [ 8 => "One" ],
  [ 3=>"Two" ]
]
```

How can I like explode all the associative arrays into one array like this

```
[
  8 => "One",
  3 =>"Two"
]
```

I tried using `array_merge(...$my_array)` and all it gives is

```
[
  0 => "One"
  1 => "Two"
]
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/80836 help?

Comment: Not really, it gives the same results as `array_merge()`

Comment: Brendon-Van-Heyzen's comment in the link Andreas has posted has a function that will output `Array([8] => One [3] => Two)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in plain php, and assuming those arrays will always look like that:
(if you're not sure you should loop through the sub_array to get the keys)

```
foreach($my_array as $sub_array ){
    $new_array[key($sub_array)] = $sub_array[key($sub_array)];
}
var_export($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it, by using Collection and the `mapWithKeys` method :

```php
$a = [
        [
           8 => "One",
        ],
        [
           3 => "Two",
        ],
     ];

$b = collect($a)->mapWithKeys(function($a) {
   return $a;
})->toArray();

dd($b);

// [
//  8 => "One"
//  3 => "Two"
// ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through both levels to get the keys

```
foreach ($my_array as $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $key => $value) {
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```